# How to compress increasing sequences of integers in ascending order in Python

Tags: python, compression

I have a 2D list with about 1.5M lists inside, each list stores an increasing sequence of unique positive integers ranging from 0 to 450K. There are total around 2.1B numbers stored in this 2D list. The distribution of list lengths is shown in graph. I will access this list frequently by rows. Is there a good way to compress and decompress it? Is there any existing implementation available in Python that does this?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

First you could use `array` to use four-bytes for each integer. For your array stored in memory in Python, that would result in significant compression -- more than a factor of three.

Second you could pack the values into 19-bit integers, since that's the minimum needed to represent 0..450000. Another factor of 1.7.

Third you could use arithmetic coding, where the probability for the next symbol is one over the number of remaining integers that follow the last one. That would get it down from 19 bits to about 10 bits on average per integer, assuming a list length of 1400. Another factor of 1.9.

Fourth you could use arithmetic coding, where the probability of the next symbol depends on the symbol, normalizing a histogram for the integers above the last integer. That factor depends on the imbalance of the histogram.

You could search for Python packages that do arithmetic coding.